# How to perform pause in following code VBA

Tags: excel, vba, time, pause

so I have timer for two activities and the idea was when the timer starts for second activity, timer of first activity freezes until second activity ends. It seems to work on first look, userform shows that first activity timer freezes but, somehow it continues to run in "background", as soon as I end with second activity, timer of first activity show whole time that has passed.

This is my module of measuring activities:

```
Option Explicit

Public TimerActive As Boolean
Public FirstLoginTime As Date
Public CurrentActivityTime As Date
Public CurrentActivityTime1 As Date
Public PreviousLoginHours As Date


'To update Activity and Other hours on all the cards available on Activity Tracker

Sub Timer()
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   
    If TimerActive Then
        
        Dim TotalTime, ActivityTime, ActivityTime1
        
        TotalTime = Format(((Now() - FirstLoginTime) + PreviousLoginHours), "HH:MM:SS")
        
        If CurrentActivityTime > 0 Then
            
            ActivityTime = Format(((Now() - CurrentActivityTime)), "HH:MM:SS")
            ActivityTracker.CurrentActivityHours.Caption = ActivityTime
        End If
        
        If CurrentActivityTime1 > 0 Then
            
            ActivityTime1 = Format(((Now() - CurrentActivityTime1)), "HH:MM:SS")
            ActivityTime = Format(((Now() - CurrentActivityTime) - (Now() - CurrentActivityTime1)), "HH:MM:SS")
            ActivityTracker.CurrentActivityHours1.Caption = ActivityTime1
            ActivityTracker.CurrentActivityHours.Caption = ActivityTime
        
        
        End If
        
        Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "Timer"
        ActivityTracker.WorkingHours.Caption = TotalTime
        
        
    End If
        
        
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Exit Sub
    
ErrorHandler:
    
  MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
  
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

And this is my start button:

```
Private Sub cmdStart_Click()
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Me.txtDate = TodayDate()                                                'Date user defined function
    
    'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
 
 If Me.lstActivityCode.Value = "Break" Then                                 'If Task is Break then no validation requried
    
    CurrentActivityTime = Now()
    Call Add_StartEntry(Me.lstActivityCode.Value, True, CurrentActivityTime) 'Checked
    Call Lock_UserInput
    
 
 ElseIf Validation = True And Me.lstActivityCode.Value <> "Break" Then      'If task is not break then validation required.
    
    CurrentActivityTime = Now()
    Call Add_StartEntry(Me.lstActivityCode.Value, True, CurrentActivityTime)
    Call Lock_UserInput
    
              
 Else
 
    Exit Sub
    
 End If
End Sub
```

I also have start button for second activity, the code is the same as for the first one.

Comment: Would you please let me know, what is the purpose of the timers? Is the purpose to timestamp how long the activities took to run, or are you trying to just pause the first sub, while the second sub is running? Are you calling the second sub from the first sub, or are you calling the first and second subs from another sub?

Comment: Purpose is to track the employees activities, they have maximum 2 activities which they can do at the same time, so basically if they are doing certain activity which is measured by first timer, and if at the some point of the time second activity pops up, they turn on second timer, while the first one should be on pause until the second activity ends.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Tomislav for the clarification. Timer will always return the current seconds count from midnight. I wrote this using the Now function instead of Timer, but it should give the same result you are looking for. I think you may be looking for something like this.

```
Option Explicit
Dim Activity_1_Timer As Double
Dim MyTimer_1 As Double
Dim Activity_1_Running As Boolean

Dim Activity_2_Timer As Double
Dim MyTimer_2 As Double
Dim Activity_2_Running As Boolean

Dim TimerDiff_1 As Double
Dim TimerDiff_2 As Double

Private Sub Btn_Activity_1_Timestamp_Click()
    If Activity_1_Running = True Then
        TimerDiff_1 = MyTimer_1 - Now
        If Activity_2_Running = False Then
            Activity_1_Timer = Activity_1_Timer + TimerDiff_1
        Else
            TimerDiff_2 = MyTimer_2 - Now
            Activity_1_Timer = Activity_1_Timer + TimerDiff_1 - TimerDiff_2
        End If
    End If
    MyTimer_1 = Now
    Debug.Print "Act 1: " & Format(Activity_1_Timer, "hh:mm:ss")
    Activity_1_Running = True
    Activity_2_Running = False
End Sub

Private Sub Btn_Activity_2_Timestamp_Click()
    If Activity_2_Running = True Then
        TimerDiff_2 = MyTimer_2 - Now
        If Activity_1_Running = False Then
            Activity_2_Timer = Activity_2_Timer + TimerDiff_2
        Else
            TimerDiff_1 = MyTimer_1 - Now
            Activity_2_Timer = Activity_2_Timer + TimerDiff_2 - TimerDiff_1
        End If
    End If
    MyTimer_2 = Now
    Debug.Print "Act 2: " & Format(Activity_2_Timer, "hh:mm:ss")
    Activity_2_Running = True
    Activity_1_Running = False
End Sub

Private Sub Btn_Reset_Click()
    Activity_1_Timer = 0
    Activity_2_Timer = 0
    
    MyTimer_1 = 0
    MyTimer_2 = 0
    
    Activity_1_Running = False
    Activity_2_Running = False
    
    Debug.Print "Act 1: " & Format(Activity_1_Timer, "hh:mm:ss")
    Debug.Print "Act 2: " & Format(Activity_2_Timer, "hh:mm:ss")
End Sub
```